# Sending post action via a thank you page (embedded mailchimp)

Tags: php, forms, post, http-post, mailchimp

For some reason I've always had trouble with forms, not sure why.

I have an embedded form that was created with MailChimp (currently located here: [dev.pagovernmentrelations.com/sign-up/](http://dev.pagovernmentrelations.com/sign-up/)).

They have the embed code set up to send the data through the form action property: **action="//xxxx.us3.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=####&id=###"**

This method does not provide a thank you page normally. After editing it, I found a way to send users to a pop-up window with a thank you from MailChimp. It is very basic and takes users away from the site, so I don't want to use it.

I changed the form action to send users to a new page, **action="/thank-you"**, where I can have a personalized thank you page (using a relative "thank you" link that can be reused on multiple sites).

Now that users are on the thank you page, I can use the `<?php echo $_POST[] ;?>` data to personalize the page. My problem is, how do I send the data to the MailChimp server located in the original form action property (**//xxxx.us3.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=####&id=###**)?

Comment: It appears you can get mailchimp to redirect to your own hosted thank you page after processing the form: http://kb.mailchimp.com/lists/signup-forms/design-and-host-your-own-thank-you-pages

Comment: @GluePear It does from there to a point. Unfortunately it only allows absolute URLs which is not what I need. I need something that allows a relative URL such as /thank-you/